Is there a way to skip jobs inside a matrix for github actions
I have built a mock pipeline that works as specified: Before start, you can select, which environments the pipeline should run on (dev, staging, prod) and then the pipeline triggers the job based on the environments inside the matrix.
My problem is that the jobs are getting started even if the env is not selected in the workflow dispatch (and then stopped afterwards), but it still gets assigned a workflow runner and is showed as successfully completed and not skipped.
Is there a way to only give the green success status to the jobs that have run for a certain env? In the image provided, I had only selected dev as env, but it still ran through all 3 envs.

name: Trigger Environment Jobs

on:
  workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      environments:
        description: "Comma-separated list of environments to trigger (e.g., dev,staging,prod)"
        required: true
        default: "dev,staging,prod"

jobs:
  deploy:
    name: Deploy to Selected Environments
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        env: [dev, staging, prod]
    steps:
      - name: Check if Environment is Selected
        id: check-env
        run: |
          selected_environments="${{ github.event.inputs.environments }}"
          if echo "$selected_environments" | grep -q "${{ matrix.env }}"; then
            echo "::set-output name=run::true"
          else
            echo "::set-output name=run::false"
          fi
        shell: bash

      - name: Deploy to ${{ matrix.env }}
        if: steps.check-env.outputs.run == 'true'
        run: |
          echo "Deploying to ${{ matrix.env }} environment"
          # Add environment-specific logic here

